# javascript - datatables reload button not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

EDIT: The button was not visible which was my original problem which is not yet solved. Thanks for the quick comments about the comma issue.

I am a JS novice and new to datatables as well. I was taking the example posted here to define the button during initialisation: 
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom

But it seems to be not working (button is not visible). 
JSFiddle link here: https://jsfiddle.net/gr5er1pj/222/

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table =  $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Reload',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                dt.ajax.reload();
            }
        }
    ]
   } );
});
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after your ajax url.

Comment: Thanks, it fixes the data problem but the "reload" button is still not visible.

Comment: @ScottSelby: The code is still not working after the edit, the problem is button is still not getting displayed.

Comment: Are you missing the dataTables.buttons.min.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add this to your script (you probably also needed dataTables.buttons.min.js):

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
```

See the working fiddle:

[https://jsfiddle.net/gr5er1pj/231/](https://jsfiddle.net/gr5er1pj/232/)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, but I am getting a link instead of a button and it replaces the combo box which filter "5,10,25,50,100" entries per page. Is it possible to control the placement of the button such that it is not affected?

Comment: You might have some cached css or something. Check your debugger (F12 in Chrome) to see if all of your required resources are loading. G'luck!

Comment: Also check here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom to see which features you actually want to show: filter, table, pagination control....

Comment: @cristianorbs and CodeLikeBeaker: Thanks so much for the help, much appreciated!